# How to use the phrase "would have" in a sentence

Tags: phrase-usage, causative-have

Should I use ***would have*** if I am talking about something that could happen because of what someone did? I am always confused about this. For example:

> If you told her, you **would have** seen the play. And if you didn't you would probably have seen it.

And should I also use it if I am telling a story about my past, and there is something that could also happen in the future but I expect to happen in the past. For example:

> When I was a kid anything I expected **would have** happen and if I didn't it wouldn't have.

Answer (score 1):

How to use **would have** in a sentence:

If you **had told me**, I **would have seen the play**.

This **would not have happened** to me at any other time in my life.

I would have gone, if you had told me.

Anything I would have expected to happen when I was a child, did happen.

If I **won** the lottery, I **would have** a lot of money. [standard grammar]

Many people say:
If I win the lottery, I would have a lot of money. [what you see and hear "out there" in the media, conversations and online]